# XSL Stylesheet Unknown formatting exception

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL and trying to "port" an xsl-stylesheet previously used for a java-application to C# (the application itself is a port from an old Java Application so the same data will be produced in the final PDF which is the objective of the service I'm developing). I get the following error when trying to call the REST-Service:

http://imgur.com/edit

The exception occurs when loading the xsl file:

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public static void MakePdf(XmlDocument xslFoDocument, Stream outputStream)
    {
        FonetDriver driver = PdfPrinterDriver.InitFonetDriver();
        driver.Render(xslFoDocument, outputStream);
    }
```

The code it refers to at this point (I get a lot of errors but this is the one I'm stuck at atm), It seems as if my app doesn't recognize w3.org/2000/svg.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  exclude-result-prefixes="">
```

http://pastebin.com/g26hKR3q

Anyone who knows what might be causing this and how I can solve it?

I'm using the FO.NET lib.

EDIT: Complete Stacktrace of the issue:

```
System.SystemException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233087
Message=System.SystemException: Unknown formatting object http://www.w3.org/2000/svg^svg
at Fonet.FonetDriver.FireFonetError(String message)
at Fonet.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.StartElement(String uri, String localName, Attributes attlist)
at Fonet.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.Parse(XmlReader reader)
Source=Fonet
StackTrace:
   at Fonet.FonetDriver.FireFonetError(String message)
   at Fonet.Fo.FOTreeBuilder.Parse(XmlReader reader)
   at Fonet.FonetDriver.Render(XmlReader inputReader, Stream outputStream)
   at Fonet.FonetDriver.Render(TextReader inputReader, Stream outputStream)
   at Fonet.FonetDriver.Render(XmlDocument doc, Stream outputStream)
   at MyRESTService.PdfPrinterDriver.MakePdf(XmlDocument xslFoDocument, Stream outputStream) in c:\Users\Jonathan Lind\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyRESTService\MyRESTService\PdfPrinterDriver.cs:line 61
   at MyRESTService.PdfPrinterDriver.MakePdf(XmlDocument xslFoDocument, String outputFileAbsolutePath) in c:\Users\Jonathan Lind\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyRESTService\MyRESTService\PdfPrinterDriver.cs:line 50
   at MyRESTService.ProductRESTService.GetPDFList(String apiquery, String template) in c:\Users\Jonathan Lind\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyRESTService\MyRESTService\ProductRESTService.svc.cs:line 95
   at SyncInvokeGetPDFList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
InnerException:
```

Comment: Please make your question self-contained + provide a **reproducible** example (XML and XSLT).

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I'm sorry for linking to other sources for code but the reason I did this was that it didn't work to write the code here at SO. I don't know what the reason for that is (I'm new here) but for some reason it didn't show up in preview. The data I'm working with is sensitive and can't be shared. I was just hoping that someone have had this issue before and knew what might be wrong. I understand if this means that you can't help but I wanted to give it a shot. Sorry!

Comment: Please consult the help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Thank you, It worked now (Don't know what I might have done wrong the last attempt. I also added the full stack trace. It says that there is an unknown formatting object (http://www.w3.org/2000/svg^svg

Comment: FO.Net doesn't support SVG I believe (See https://fonet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ)

Comment: Thank you @TimC, That could explain the exception:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG is a W3C recommendation, an XML format to describe vector graphics. I think Apache Fop works together with Apache Batik in the Java world to allow you to insert a rasterization of a vector graphics in the final PDF. The .NET FOP processor you use does not seem to know how to deal with the SVG graphics.